# Put text into non-active Axes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text, plot, axes, mlint

Most MATLAB plotting commands allow you to specify which axes to act on, for instance

```
plot (x,y)
```

plots in the current axes, but

```
plot(Ax, x, y)
```

will plot in the axes Ax.

Similarly, you can label the x- or y- axis of a non-active axes

```
xlabel(Ax, 'this label goes on the x-axis of Ax whether or not Ax == gca')
```

But the text command doesn't appear to support this feature.  Is there a way to put text into a non-active axes?

I ask because this sequence:

```
currentAxes = gca;
axes(Ax); %MLINT warning here
text(x,y,'this text ends up on axes Ax now');
axes(currentAxes); %MLINT warning here
```

will throw MLINT warnings that calling axes(axes_handle) is slow in scripted functions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the 'Parent' property in calling the text command

```
text(x,y,'text','Parent', Ax)
```